# Producer/consumer with monitoring semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, monitoring, semaphore

I'm tring to solve producer consumer problem by using monitoring thread.
Basically, when we try to solve this problem, we can easly solve it by using semaphore and mutex(semaphore detect empty or full state keep stable critical section, and mutex keep shared part where producer producing, consumer consuming)

In this problem I want to using monitoring thread to check how many item is in shared memory and this thread must enter critical section after producer or consumer doing their work. It kind of acknowledgement thing

For example

Produce
Ack, buffer have 1 item

Consume
Ack, buffer have 0 item

Produce
Ack, buffer have 1 item

Produce
Ack, buffer have 2 item

I was thinking use two more sem_t,

```
sem_t m1;
sem_t m2;

Void *produce()
{
  sem_wait(&m1);
  sem_wait(&m2);
  ....
  sem_signal(&m1);

}
Void *consumer()
{
  sem_wait(&m1);
  sem_wait(&m2);
  ....
  sem_signal(&m2);
}

Void *monitor()
{
   if(m1==o && m2==1)
   sem_wait();
   else if(m1==1 && m2==0)
   sem_wait(m1);
  ....
  sem_signal(m1);
  sem_signal(m2);
}
```

producer and consumer only can enter critical section when both m1 and m2 is bigger then 0, and when they done their tasks they call sem_signal just one time for m1 or m2. this block producer and consumer, only monitoring thread can enter critical section. after monitoring thread finishing own task, it calls sem_signal for m1, m2, then producer or consumer can enter the critical section   (each of sem object is kind of mutex, binary semaphore)

but it doesn't work..
I can't find what is my problem.
Is Sem object can't use if statement?
or, my idea is have something problem?

thanks for reading my long text

Comment: First off see [mcve], next define "it doesn't work"

Comment: Kevin - Thank you for comment I feel shame about my fool question I will try more and find more solution after sleep